# Files uploaded through Django admin console have wrong permissions

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a section of my website cordoned off simply as a repository/free hosting service for projects I make. I have a simple Django project called `personal` dedicated to this within my website - the process, ideally, is

1. Upload a file to the `personal` database, via the admin console (via `mysite.com/admin`)

   - this is saved at `/static/media/personal/[foldername]/myproject`
2. Assign that file a short tag (e.g. `myproject`)
3. That file should now be accessible to anyone at `mysite.com/personal/myproject`, which will redirect to the static file I uploaded.

My issue is that the files I upload are getting saved with permissions `0600`, so when I try to access them later with my web browser I get a 403 Forbidden error. I can go in to the server manually and change the permissions to `0644` and then it works fine, but I'd like Django to do this for me.

---

I've already tried putting the following in my website's `settings.py` file:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
```

which was the only real thing I was able to find through my research that I could understand. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have helped. The model I'm using for this `personal` database is as follows:

```
def generate_filename(instance, filename):
    if instance.folder and len(instance.folder) > 0:
        return os.path.join('personal', instance.folder, filename)
    else:
        return 'personal/{}'.format(filename)


class PersonalFile(models.Model):
    """
    A model type representing a single file. Contains only that
    file object.
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ---> {}".format(self.name, str(self.file))

    """ The url for accessing this file """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    """ A description for this project """
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    """ Whether this item should be displayed on the projects index """
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    """ A folder for this object to be placed in """
    folder = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    """ The actual media url of the file """
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)
```

Note that I haven't had problems with the *folder* getting the wrong permissions, just the file that's supposed to go in it.

I'm using a standard Django/gunicorn/nginx stack for deployment. For simplicity's sake I'd like to handle this at the Django level, but if it'd be easier to modify some nginx config files or something then that'd work too.

Comment: you should run the gunicorn process with the same user as nginx (www-data usually). Probably your gunicorn process isn't running with the correct user and so the user can't set the permissions to the correct group. Check the ownership of the files (`ls -al`). Also make sure the entire directory path is accessible (`/static` and `/static/media` have the correct owner and permissions).

Comment: How do I check what user nginx and gunicorn are running with now? I know they're both running as daemon services, does that affect anything?